# Single java field gets mapped to two JSON fields with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

There is a isCase field in POJO that gets mapped to case and is_case at the same time(which is not what expected).
Removing @JsonProperty annotation gets rid of is_case field in json, but is_case is what it's supposed to be.
Putting @JsonIgnore on isCase doesn't get rid of case in response json.
Renaming isCase to is_case does get rid of case in response json, but that doesn't seem too right.
Why would Jackson ever map single java field to two fields?
A POJO is declared like this:

```
public class CreateRuleResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "rule_name", required = true)
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("rule_num")
    private String ruleNum;

    @JsonProperty(value = "rule_category")
    private RuleCategory ruleCategory;

    @JsonProperty(value = "rule_status")
    private RuleStatus ruleStatus;

    @JsonProperty(value = "rule_channel_type")
    private String ruleChannelType;

    @JsonProperty("action")
    private RuleAction ruleAction;

    @JsonProperty("is_case")
    private Boolean isCase;

    public CreateRuleResponse() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRuleNum() {
        return ruleNum;
    }

    public void setRuleNum(String ruleNum) {
        this.ruleNum = ruleNum;
    }

    public RuleCategory getRuleCategory() {
        return ruleCategory;
    }

    public void setRuleCategory(RuleCategory ruleCategory) {
        this.ruleCategory = ruleCategory;
    }

    public RuleStatus getRuleStatus() {
        return ruleStatus;
    }

    public void setRuleStatus(RuleStatus ruleStatus) {
        this.ruleStatus = ruleStatus;
    }

    public String getRuleChannelType() {
        return ruleChannelType;
    }

    public void setRuleChannelType(String ruleChannelType) {
        this.ruleChannelType = ruleChannelType;
    }

    public RuleAction getRuleAction() {
        return ruleAction;
    }

    public void setRuleAction(RuleAction ruleAction) {
        this.ruleAction = ruleAction;
    }

    public Boolean getCase() {
        return isCase;
    }

    public void setCase(Boolean aCase) {
        isCase = aCase;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's mapping the variables and also the getter methods.

Comment: But why would this not happen to every other field?

Comment: Because isCase is the conventional name for the getter method for a boolean named "case" . Now you have a JSON property "isCase" defined by your annotation, and also the JSON property "case" because the library infers that your isCase() method is used to access a boolen named "case".  For the other fields, the property name in your annotation is the same as the property name implied from your getter functions, so there is only one distinct property name to display for each of these variables.

Comment: Change the name of getRuleAction() to getPoop() and watch what happens.

Comment: By convention, the getter for isCase should be isIsCase(), since it is a boolean . Or you can change the variable isCase to just "case" and name the getter as isCase() to match them up.

Comment: This makes sense, but at the same time there is a ruleAction property with getter getRuleAction, and annotated by just "action", wouldn't it make sense for rule_action property to also appear in json because of the getter method? Or does the fact that getRuleAction is conventional name for ruleAction property make it so that rule_action field does not pop up?

Comment: I think what happens it that jackson looks at the getter and the variable and respects that they have the same natural property name, and infers what it considers to be a single property arrived at by two different means.

Comment: @EmberTraveller this is happening because the field name `ruleAction` and the getter `getRuleAction()` are matching (except the `get` prefix which is the convention for the getter). If you rename this getter method to something like `getXyz()` then it will also create 2 fields for that.

Comment: @LowKeyEnergy by convention the getter for `isCase` should be `getIsCase()` because it is a `Boolean`, not a `boolean`.

Comment: `isXxx()` also works for `Boolean` named xxx , not just `boolean`.

Comment: Yes, it does work. But it would be better to rename the variable to `case` with the `@JsonProperty("is_case")` annotation and the getter method should be either `getCase()` or `isCase()` both will work.

Comment: @MushifAliNawaz It is not possible to rename variable to case because case is a reserved keyword

Comment: Ohhhhh! Busted!

Comment: @EmberTraveller oh, yes, I missed that. You can rename it to `_case` then.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you name it. The point is that the getter and the field name should match for Jackson to treat it as a single field. Otherwise, it will create 2 fields, one for the field name and another for the getter method.

Comment: *The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "_".* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 1):

Rename this getter method from `getCase()` to `getIsCase()` (following the convention). Jackson is treating it as 2 different fields because the getter and the field name do not match.